# Unable to install Cyanogenmod in GT I9000

Tags: rom-flashing

I have done something very wrong with my GT I9000 devices.
i rooted and install cyanogenmod and it works for 2 months, but after that it went into boot loop and while troubleshooting i make the device unusable.
I again rooted the device via ODIN and install sempaphore KK_3.4.3s and after that try to install cyanogenmod 11 kitkat pacakge via external SD cards but everytime getting error:

error: installation aborted.

From error logs:
I:cant partition non mmcblk device :/devices/platform/s3c-sdhci.2/mmc_host/mmc2

Pls help me in providing slution via ODIN only as ADB is not getting connected.

Thanks

Comment: Can I assume that you have a custom recovery installed?

Answer (score 0):

First go to the download mode
Volume Down & Home & Power 
Now install stock GT-I9000 using ODIN from firmware in XDA [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1196179). Root and then install Semaphore_2.7.4.tar from [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_galaxysmtd). Alternatively you can also install recovery from Replicant website (my preference). First install CM10.1.2. check if the phone is working fine. Then download, cm11 go to recovery, wipe data/factory reset + wipe cache partition. Wiping cache is *important* otherwise you will endup in a boot cycle. This is necessary as the partitions are different in cm11 in comparison to cm10.x. Do not directly flash cm11 on stock.